# Displaying Image in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, ionic-framework

and I want to display an image im my `<img src>`
when I clicked the button select image it displays all the information of the image but it doesn't show any img at all. I call the information of the image in my app.js using .directive

```
.directive("filesInput", function() {

    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function postLink($scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            elem.on("change", function(e) {

                var files = elem[0].files;
                ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
                // var imageData = _.map(files, 'name');
                $scope.img = files;
                console.log(files);


            })
        }
    }
});
```

How can I call the .directive("filesInput") to my controller to display in my .html

```
<img src="{{files}}">
```

Comment: code on plunker pls

Comment: Have you tried using ng-src instead of src e.g. <img ng-src="{{files}}"> as angular evaluates the expression after it has been loaded with ng-src, but not src

Comment: @UpalRoy https://plnkr.co/edit/8pohuO2gUf7zgkK5fdac?p=preview I dont have any in my controller yet.

Comment: @RobertAnderson and yes i tried the ng-src

Comment: I had a quick look at the code, i think the problem is in the directive, where it is setting the image. So it sets the scope img but no the variable. The img would need the full path e.g. <img ng-src="{{img}}"> or depending on the location you would need to prepend the image path before it such as <img ng-src="'/pathofimage/' + {{img}}">

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is in the directive, where it is setting the image. So it sets the scope img but not the variable. The img would need the full path e.g.

```
<img ng-src="{{img}}">
```

or depending on the location you would need to prepend the image path before it such as

```
<img ng-src="'/pathofimage/' + {{img}}">
```